# Convexity of the function $f(x, y) = ||x|| - ||y||, x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am attempting this question:

Determine the convexity of the function $$f(x, y) = ||x|| - ||y||, x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$$

I tried to use the definition of a convex function, but it doesn't seem to lead to a conclusion. Any hint on how I should proceed? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider the function $f$ restricted to the subspace
$\{ (0,y) \mid y \in \mathbb R^n\}$.